# Set focus onload of TinyMce editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

When click on edit button it displays tinymce text editor but the problem is it does not set focus on first load of editor from second onward it work fine

Below is what i have tried

HTML

```
<h3>History Review <a href="#" class="blue_edit_btn" id="history_review_link" onclick="bgshoweditor('history_review')" >Edit</a></h3>
```

JQuery

```
function bgshoweditor(editorid)
{

    $("#"+editorid+"_div").hide();
    $("#"+editorid).show(); 
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, editorid );
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, editorid );
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus', false, editorid );      
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.select(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody(), true);
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.collapse(false); 
}
```

Comment: for me first time it will occur,but for the other times,it won't work :(

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the `mceFocus` command is removed in `TinyMce 4` (I said this, because in 4.x removed `mceRemoveControl` and `mceAddControl` removed).

So, I recommend to use the [`.focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)

try this :

```
tinyMCE.get(editorid).focus();
```

[Working Example](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/5heaab)

OR you can use the [`auto_focus`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aauto_focus) property.

> auto_focus: This option enables you to auto focus an editor instance.

**Note: auto_focus set focus on editor when it's load**

Comment: i know this is working  but in my page there are 40 tinymce so it will take more time to load. thats why i am loading it on run time i.e. when user click on edit button it loads one tiny mce editor not others

Comment: this doesnt seem to work if the editor in wp is in text mode. SO I assume this only function if the tinyMCE is init on load, and remains the editor. `tinyMCE.get(editorid).focus();` works a treat otherwise. 

Im testing like so: 

`var editorState = ( tinyMCE.activeEditor == null || tinyMCE.activeEditor.isHidden() !== false ) ? false : true;`

The attempting to set focus:
` if ( editorState === true ) { tinyMCE.get('content').focus(); } else { $('textarea#content').focus(); }`

`file_name.js?ver=6dce954…:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may work for you

```
function bgshoweditor(editorid)
{

$("#"+editorid+"_div").hide();
$("#"+editorid).show(); 
 if (tinyMCE.activeEditor == null || tinyMCE.activeEditor.isHidden() != false) {
     tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, editorid );
 }
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, editorid );
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus', false, editorid );      
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.select(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody(), true);
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.collapse(false); 
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it is not working for my case...Functions works for 2nd time but not on first time

Answer (score 0):

for tinyMCE v4+

```
tinymce.activeEditor.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are looking for a solution for the VUE thin plugin `@tinymce/tinymce-vue`

```
import { getTinymce } from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue/lib/es2015/main/ts/TinyMCE'

const tinyMCE = getTinymce()
tinyMCE.activeEditor.focus()
```